# How to change the EditText Hint depends upon the spinner item selection in android

Tags: android, spinner

I am trying to set hint in `EditText` according to the selection of spinner item.
I have two items in my spinner. i.e KG and LBS, Now what i want to do is when i select KG in spinner then KG( Hint) should be set in the `EditText` or when i select LBS in spinner then LBS(Hint) should be set in the `EditText`. I have tried this in my if condition,KG is already set but when i change my selection to LBS in spinner then value(Hint) is not changing in the `EditText`.
Here is my code:

```
final Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
etweight=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight);


    this.arraySpinner= new  String[]{
            "KG", "LBS"
    };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arraySpinner);
    s.setAdapter(adapter);


    if (s.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("KG")) {

        etweight.setHint("KG");

    } else if (s.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("LBS")) {

        etweight.setHint("LBS");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it works

```
 s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if(position == 0)
                    etweight.setHint("KG");
                else
                    etweight.setHint("LBS");

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this use `setOnItemSelectedListener` of spinner

```
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                   int arg2, long arg3) {
            String text=spin.getSelectedItem().toString();

            if (text.equals("KG")) {

                etweight.setHint("KG");

            } else if (text.equals("LBS")) {

                etweight.setHint("LBS");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```